# Azure SQL Db to DB2 Sync

Tags: database, synchronization

I need to automatically synchronize changes made in an Azure SQL database to our DB2 system. Whenever a change is made in Azure, DB2 should also be modified.

Azure DB creation is not started and table schema will be the same except for new modification details columns.

This activity is done as part of mainframe to cloud migration and there are other applications(not part of migration) that use the same tables. Because of this some tables need Azure SQL to DB2 sync and others need DB2 to Azure sync .

The organization has previously used Attunity replicate for DB2 to azure sync. This cannot be used for Azure to DB2 sync because of its limitations with db2 as a target.

My current options are :

- Batch program used with triggers in azure DB
- Azure data factory

Which is my best option? The answer does not have to be limited to the above options.